# PostGIS Web service call function

Tags: postgis, geoserver, tomcat, apache

I have spatial function in my PostgreSQL/PostGIS DB that when sent a set of coordinates (Long Lat) returns single value. I am not a web developer but I would like to serve the function up as a web service.

GeoServer and Apache Tomcat are currently installed on the same server.

Is there is way to use the existing infrastructure to call the function?

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to install a new service, you can use [pg_featureserv](https://github.com/CrunchyData/pg_featureserv) to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can install an additional service https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest and call it using the API